# PaperTrail: how to differentiate whodunnit when we track changes by both Users *and* AdminUsers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Our model's `whodunnit` value is a string - for example `"22"` as in the `User` with an `id` of `22`.

The problem is we use both the `User` and `AdminUser` models to track whodunnit. As such, it is impossible to tell if a change was made by a User or, instead, by an AdminUser:

```
def user_for_paper_trail
  current_user || current_admin_user
end
```

I'm a bit new to PaperTrail but worked my way through their docs and couldn't come up with any solutions. It might be a strange request, but I'd love for something like an arbitrary field which we could add a value for as a whodunnit `type`, if that makes sense. Or a way to only track certain changes depending on the controller (which would work in this case since I'd only track changes which were made via the AdminPanel).

Thanks for any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: Using an unified `User` model differentiating admins by roles is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PaperTrail is storing the `id` because of one of these two reasons:

- Whodunnit is being assigned using the default before_action that PaperTrail provides and is calling `.id` on the value returned by `your user_for_paper_trail` method.

or

- Your app manually calls `.id` on the results of your `user_for_paper_trail` method.

Since the `User` or `AdminUser` `id`s are not universally unique, you should store a different value.

The `whodunnit` value can be any string you decide.  If you have a unique identifier that can be used to differentiate between `Users` and `AdminUsers` you should store that value.

I am thinking one of these options may solve your problem:

1. If `email` is unique between the two user models, store the email instead of the id.
2. If `email` is not unique, you could store a string that shows both the user model type and the id (e.g. `'User: 1'` and/or `'AdminUser: 1'`), then when you go to fetch the `whodunnit` value you can parse the string for the user model and the id, then use that information as appropriate.
3. Read through how [PaperTrail details how to find out who was responsible for a change](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4a-finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change) and come up with a similar custom solution (or, [another option](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/wiki/Setting-whodunnit-in-the-rails-console)).

Comment: Thank you @ecnalyr. I feel like #2 is what in line for what I was hoping for, but I didn't see anything about that in the docs you linked (I had read them earlier today - perhaps I missed it).

Comment: For future explorers: leaning on the solution above, I decided to add a `before_filter` to the model's admin panel. Within it I set the value for `whodunnit` as such: `PaperTrail.whodunnit = "AdminUser: #{current_admin_user.id}"`